# Ruby on Rails: implementing search and other. Missing template error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, partials

I've followed the RoR hartl tutorial with the 'like twitter' app, and I want to modify it a bit, implementing search bar to search for users with a given name, and 'changing' the follow/unfollow option to Endorsement system, where a user can endorse another user, having 3 endorsements a month, but cant endorse same user twice a month.

Encountering some problems now. When visiting a user profile page, the endorse form appears and you can endorse him and remove the endorse.
But when I use the search bar from the main page, i get:

> *Missing partial search/_endorse_form, application/_endorse_form with*

I've got partials:

**shared/_endorse_form.html.erb**

```
<% unless current_user?(@user) %>
  <div id="endorse_form">
  <% if current_user.endorsing?(@user) %>
    <%= render 'shared/unendorse' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'shared/endorse' %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**shared/_endorse.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(current_user.active_endorsements.build) do |f| %>
  <div><%= hidden_field_tag :endorsed_id, @user.id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Endorse", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <%= f.text_field :comment, class: 'form-control' %>
<% end %>
```

**shared/_unendorse.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(current_user.active_endorsements.find_by(endorsed_id: @user.id),
             html: { method: :delete }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Remove endorse", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

**Now about search controller:**

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController

  def search
    query = "%#{params[:query]}%"
    @users = User.where("name LIKE ? ", query)
  end

end
```

**and the view:**

```
<%= render 'shared/search_bar' %>
<ul class="users follow">
  <%= render @users %>
</ul>
<%= will_paginate %>
```

So that's that, i want the partials in the shared folder so i can render them on pages like "All users" or when searching for a user, so it can appear next to the search results etc. Hope you get the point.

Now, also when i move the shared partials to let's say the users view folder, and remove the *'shared/'* from renders, the **searching works**, but i cannot get
the partials to show next to the searching results and getting an error:

> *undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass*

```
Extracted source (around line #2):

<%= form_for(current_user.active_endorsements.build) do |f| %>
  <div><%= hidden_field_tag :endorsed_id, @user.id %></div>
  <!-- not sure about the current_user.id!!!!!!!!!!1 -->
  <%= f.submit "Endorse", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <%= f.text_field :comment, class: 'form-control' %>
<% end %>
```

I certainly feel like i am missing something important.. Anyone has an idea how to PROPERLY solve this issue?

Best regards,
Helban

Comment: What is the `main` page code for rendering partials ?

Comment: @ahmadhamza main page? You mean page to show users i.e
users/show.html.erb ?

Comment: You said in the question `But when I use the search bar from the main page, i get:`

Comment: @ahmadhamza It's in static_pages/home which also renders partials for logged in or not logge in user, which are in the same static_pages directory.
`<%= render 'static_pages/logged_in_home' %>`
That partial renders the search bar like:
`<%= render 'shared/search_bar' %>`
And there are some htmls like 
`<section class="user_info">
      <%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
    </section>`

Comment: I'm asking what is the code that you have written to render those partials in the main page ? I need to check the code. May be you have not written the correct path ?

Comment: @ahmadhamza I'll be honest, i have no clue whatsoever what do you mean by that. So ease this out, You can see everyting here under this bitbucket link https://bitbucket.org/kramarz/pracainzynierska/src

Answer (score 1):

I saw the code. 
The file `app/views/users/show.html.erb` was showing `template missing`. The path for the partial was wrong.

```
<%= render 'endorse_form' if logged_in? %>
```

But it should be

```
<%= render 'shared/endorse_form' if logged_in? %>
```

You need to mention the `folder name` in the `render` if you are calling partials from `another folder`.

So here, you are calling partials `shared` folder from `user` folder.

Hope you got the point.

Comment: If that helped please mark it as a correct answer. (That Tick)

Comment: Thanks, but thats because i pushed the wrong code actually, yes i was aware of that, and know how it should look like.
The problem im really having is that
`<div><%= hidden_field_tag :endorsed_id, @user.id %></div>`
returns **undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass**
For the @user variable.
@users variable contains the search results, each found user. 
In the form_for in the endorse partial in hidden_field_tag i need to pass the endorsed_id (to whom) and user.id (from who - current logged in user). So i want @user.id to contain id of the each user displayed in search, depending on the click

Comment: I am missing something here, and i cannot figure out what. In the search results, i want to render all the search results, render each user, and next to the user, render the endorse form, and depending on which button i press, the correct @user.id (the clicked user id) will be sent. so let's say string "adam" will find 4 users named adam1-4, and 4 buttons next to them, but each of the button pressed will send the correct id - the id that corresponds to the user next to the button. Hope you understand

Comment: do you want logged-in user id in that hidden field ?

Comment: (for any mods reading - sorry for the spam) 
I believe it needs to be done with something like for each. For each user (the displayed result) in users (all the displayed results) render the endorse form. But i *think* this will break the form when visiting the certain user profile, i want the form be also available when you also visit a users profile, not only in search results. edit: The endorsed_id (one getting the endorsement) and logged-in user (the one giving endorsement)

Comment: So sorry but i'm unable to understand your query. Can you please be specific ?

Comment: Alright.  think this is too much i want. At the moment, visiting a users profile, and endorsing him - all works correctly. What i wanted also is to have the endorse form in the search results, next to each found user. So when theres 2 adams, next to each i will have the endorse form working correctly. But perhaps that's too much to ask. **To simplify**: Now i would like to have the search working, without any forms. So i can search for users and then go to their profile to endorse them. And that's not working, telling me that @user doesnt exist so no .id method.

Comment: everything is in app folder, there are controllers, views with shared folder with partials. So the users and search controllers, and in views/search, views/shared and views/users

Comment: Just noticed something REALLY stupid.. the way it was now, only the search wasn't working, that was because i **commented out** a line in search.html.erb but it was STILL being interpreted!!! causing the search error.. i removed it, and now it works as it should. BUT!!!! Thats not what i wanted. If the line would stay there, i'd like it to work, that is: When searching, i get search results, and next to each result, i get the endorse form for EACH user, and the button would send the hidden info containing the Id of the person being endorsed and the id of the logged person